# Decrypt SSL with Wireshark supported browsers

Tags: tls, decryption, wireshark

I've been following the guide:
https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/

Using it for chrome and Safari on MacOS does not populate any keys in the file, Did browsers stop keys populating for security reasons or is it a must that all browsers should populate them?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Ans check this link about the methods limitation [https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#using-the-pre-master-secret:~:text=Change%20the%20SSLKEYLOGFILE,by%20the%20application](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#using-the-pre-master-secret:%7E:text=Change%20the%20SSLKEYLOGFILE,by%20the%20application)

Second, I am not sure about Mac OS, but I recently tried on Windows and this method does work. Just check, that you properly exported your Environment Variables,2. if the previous thing is right, then try lowering the protocol version of your browsers, from TLS1.3 to TLS1.2.